# Can't return JSON data on Success

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have partial view loaded in to my page which simply shows a comment box.

All I want to do is save this data in to my DB via NHibernate but initially I want to make sure the data is actually making it to my controller.

Model:

```
   public class Recommendation : Entity
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual int BookingId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Recommend { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RecommendList { get; set; }
    public virtual string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
  public class RecommendationController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Recommendation model = new Recommendation();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(Recommendation model)
    {
        string data = string.Format("You selected = {0}", model.Comments);
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { userData = data } };
    }

}
```

View:

```
    @model Breaks.Core.Model.Recommendation

<script type="text/javascript">
    var AJAX_URL = '@Url.Action("Save", "Recommendation")';
</script>
   <form id="recommendUsForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comments)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Comments, new { @class = "form-control", Name="Comments", id = "Comments" })

                    </div>


            <button type="button" value="submit" id="save">Submit</button>


            </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $(function () {
    $("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var userData = {
            Comments: $('#Comments').val()
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(userData),
            url: AJAX_URL,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click on the Submit button I do get the alert popping up, which suggests to me that I'm at least getting a success but the info in the alert is just "You selected = " and no text from the comment box.

What am I missing? Why isn't it posting back the data?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** Latest changes to my code and still getting errors. 
The error I am getting now is "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: On the controller, try to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.  `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: I've tried all of the suggestions but unfortunately I'm still getting nothing back from the success message. It doesn't help that I can't run debug on Visual Studio because it's on the other side of a payment gateway which doesn't work on localhost.

If anyone has any other suggestions or options, I'd be really greatful.

Comment: In the `$.ajax`, add these 2 lines: `dataType: 'JSON', contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`. Then in your Controller `Save` method, change the return to `return new JsonResult { Data = new { userData = data } };`.

Answer (score 0):

The property name in your JS object does not match the model in the C# code, so the ModelBinder can't do it's magic. Change `userComment` to `Comments`, assuming you want to only bind to that one property of the model, like this:

```
var userData = {
    Comments: $('#Comments').val()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but it's still just giving me a blank space where I would expect to see the comment string.

Comment: You also need to change `data: JSON.stringify(userData),` to `data: userData` (or set `contentType: 'json'`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will want to save the rest of the model data, you can serialize the form data and let the ModelBinder do the rest of the work.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $('#recommendUsForm').serialize(),
     url: AJAX_URL,
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
     }
 });
```